# JavaScript - How to get the name of the key inside a function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript literal object as shown below..

```
var db = new Observer();
var user = {
   firstName: db.observe("abc"),
   lastName: "xyz",
   middleName: db.observe("test")
};
```

NOTE:  the "firstName" value is a function call db.observe("abc") which takes a parameter.

```
var Observer = function() {
    this.observe = function (value) {  // INITIAL value of the field
        // HOW WILL I GET "key, for e.g. firstName" key here so that i can associate "value" with it.

    return this;
    }
}
```

My requirement is to get the name of the key, in this case 'firstName" in the observe() function.

OR Please feel free to recommend alternatives to achieve the same.

NOTE:  This is related to a small MVVM framework which I am experimenting with and am stuck at this point.

Let me know whether this is possible with JS.

REF:  knockoutjs does something like this... http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html

Comment: this may help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: checked the link.. but it doesn't have the required information..

Comment: Passing in the required information is not an option?? E.g. `db.observe("abc", 'firstName'), ...`?

Comment: :) no..atleast till now.. in case  I don't get any solution, I may need to go with this.

Comment: From the given code sample, I don't see any way how `Observer.observe` has a way to access the appropriate property name and actually I would be quite surprised if there was a way to do it.

Comment: @Yoshi: exactly, check this out.. http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html .. I am learning some intermediate to advanced JS skills and figuring out how libraries like this are created.. (I have a look at knockoutjs code, but not yet able to comprehend fully)

Comment: If you'll have a look at the [source](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-1.2.1.debug.js) for `ko.observable` (search for `ko.observable = `), you'll notice that it is actually returning a function which is where all the magic lies.

Comment: @Yoshi:  yes looking that function and just got a working sample ready.. thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide that type of information to the interface of the function:

```
var observation = db.observe("abc");
var other_observation = db.observe("test");
var user = {
   firstName: ( todayIsFriday ? observation : other_observation ),
   lastName: "xyz",
   middleName: ( todayIsFriday ? other_observation : observation )
};
```

You can't really expect the parser to know what to use as "key" here in the `observe` function, you'd basically need to implement a time machine in Javascript first.

So, you really need to pass it as an extra parameter, or put your db object in a sort of "state" first.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive by  [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) . see the demo below

### http://jsfiddle.net/3SwyM/2/

although its works on static names, but if your `observe()` works well then you can achieve the result also

Comment: Thanks.. checked this.. This firstName calls a db.Observe("default-value") .. and I want the key, in this case "firstName", inside of db.Observe() function which is in the Observer object.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as i just got a my sample ready.  Thanks to Yoshi's comment, which probed me to dig deeper..

I am posting the link to sample implementation here, if anyone's interested... The code is buggy but demonstrated data binding which I was trying to do POC...

Here is the jsfiddle URL...

http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshpillai/xQkXk/22/

Try changing the value in the textbox, the dependent objects are automatically updated....

Thanks all for the comment.  This is just raw/buggy, code.. Will polish this over the next couple of days...